# update value in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to edit the old values in a table

```
$row=mysql_fetch_row($res); //get two values in a row from mysql
```

`$value` is obtain from `$_GET['value']`
and is used in the following form

```
<form action="renew.php?value='.$value.'" method="POST">
    Enter your value:  <br/>
    <input type="text" name="firstvalue" size="30" value="'.$row[0].'"/><br/>
    Enter another value:<br/>
    <textarea name="secondvalue" col="10">'.$row[1].'</textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Done!"/>
</form>
```

I'd like to post this form then renew the old values in mysql table with the new firstvalue and secondvalue. I'm stuck now.

In the renew.php I try this

```
$oldvalue=$_GET['value'];
print_r($oldvalue);
$newval1=$_POST['secondvalue'];
$newval2=$_POST['firstvalue']; // An unexpected syntax error for T_VARIABLE here

$query=sprintf("UPDATE tebo SET value1='%s',value2='%s' WHERE value1='%s' LIMIT 1",
               $newval1,$newval2,$oldvalue);
mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to update the specified data. ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: You should end every line with a `;`. That is why you get the specified error. Also, please google SQL Injection and do something to prevent it. `mysql_real_escape_string()` would be a good start.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that point. my mind is totally messed up/

Comment: Happens to everyone :). Just do something with that SQL Injection problem, now your code is an invitation to people who want to mess with your site.

Comment: what you mean by `Thank you for reading, my program works.`

Comment: I mean I finish my program. it works perfectly without using wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put ; on bellow line

```
$newval1=$_POST['secondvalue'];
$newval2=$_POST['firstvalue'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$oldvalue=$_GET['value'];

$newval1=$_POST['secondvalue'];
$newval2=$_POST['firstvalue']; 

$query="UPDATE tebo SET value1='".$newval1."',value2='".$newval2."' WHERE value='".$oldvalue."' ";
mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to update the specified data. ".mysql_error());
```